# Delayed IPN with PayPal (in Sandbox and with real payments)

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

During a few days I debug with PayPal Sandbox I more than once noticed that IPN notifications are queued and are not processed for extended periods of time (maybe hours).

Is this problem specific to Sandbox?

Does it happens with regular (non-Sandbox) PayPal IPN?

If it happens, then how often (approximately) it happens?

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit to being a 'noob' with IPN (I managed to get mine working OK). I have noticed during testing that

- clicking the "Buy Now" button (which points to the Sandbox webscr) sometimes gives me a 500 error. A refresh/repost usually works.
- the Listener code doesn't like email addresses with '+' symbols in the sellers' account profile.

I'm still in development mode, so can't speak to production environment. But you might find the IPN Tester helpful (if you haven't already used it) to test your code: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/

Using the IPN Tester will help verify that your 'listener' code is returning the '200' status that is required to 'finish' the transaction. My understanding is that if the '200' status is not 'heard' by PayPal, the IPN will continue to be sent at varying intervals. So you could look at your logs to ensure the '200' is being sent properly.